# phpstorm remote host (SFTP) auto download

Tags: download, sftp, phpstorm, automatic-updates

i just add a new remote project to my phpstorm workspace. if i change some code, it will be automaticly uploaded to my server (sftp). but when something is changed there, nothing happens im my IDE... is there a solution for this? phpstorm V.6.0.

thank so much for your help.
ps: i can't change the mode to svn or any other subversion unfortunately ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is not available yet, please follow this request:

- [WI-1284](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-1284) Auto Refresh of Remote Files

Comment: It's been 5 years give or take. Now version 8 is out. What's happening with this feature and when will this feature be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I have replaced the "Save" key mapping with a macro.

That macro does include the "automatic download" (of a folder) that I need. (from remote dev stack, to local dev machine which has my repo.)

(In addition to other steps that I want to happen "automatically".)